# Iterate over fields in typesafe config

Tags: scala, typesafe

I have perks.conf:

```
autoshield {
    name="autoshield"
    price=2
    description="autoshield description"
}
immunity {
    name="immunity"
    price=2
    description="autoshield description"
}
premium {
    name="premium"
    price=2
    description="premium description"
}
starter {
    name="starter"
    price=2
    description="starter description"
}
jetpack {
    name="jetpack"
    price=2
    description="jetpack description"
}
```

And I want to iterate over perks in my application something like this:

```
val conf: Config = ConfigFactory.load("perks.conf")
val entries = conf.getEntries()
for (entry <- entries) yield {
  Perk(entry.getString("name"), entry.getInt("price"), entry.getString("description"))
}
```

But I can't find appropriate method which returns all entries from config. I tried `config.root()`, but it seems it returns all properties including system, akka and a lot of other properties.

Comment: Did you try [entrySet](http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html#entrySet())?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For example you have the following code in your `Settings.scala`

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load("perks.conf")
```

if you call `entrySet` on the root config (not `conf.root()`, but the root object of this config) it will returns many garbage, what you need to do is to place all your perks under some path in the perks.conf:

```
perks {
  autoshield {
    name="autoshield"
    price=2
    description="autoshield description"
  }
  immunity {
    name="immunity"
    price=2
    description="autoshield description"
  }
}
```

and then in the `Settings.scala` file get this config:

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load("perks.conf").getConfig("perks")
```

and then call entrySet on this config and you'll get all the entries not from the root object, but from the perks. Don't forget that Typesafe Config is written in java and entrySet returns `java.util.Set`, so you need to import `scala.collection.JavaConversions._`

Answer (score 44):

`entrySet` collapses the tree. If you want to iterate over immediate children only, use:

```
conf.getObject("perks").asScala.foreach({ case (k, v) => ... })
```

`k` will be "autoshield" and "immunity", but not "autoshield.name", "autoshield.price" etc.

This requires that you import `scala.collection.JavaConverters._`.

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer. `JavaConversions` is a super helpful piece.

Comment: No such method :-(

Answer (score 2):

```
val common = allConfig.getConfig("column.audit")
   val commonList = common.root().keySet()
      commonList.iterator().foreach( x => { 
      println("Value is :: " + x) 
    }
   )
```

This should work. But if your keyset is will print in a different order than app.conf.

e.g.:

```
> cat application.conf

`column {
  audit {
    load_ts = "current_timestamp",
    load_file_nm = "current_filename",
    load_id = "load_id"
  }`
```

the script above will print this:

```
Value is :: [load_id, load_ts, load_file_nm]
```

Answer (score 1):

`getObject` has given me a qualified json object (e.g `timeout.ms = 5` becomes `{ timeout: { ms: 5 }`).

I ended up with:

```
conf.getConfig(baseKey).entrySet().foreach { entry =>
   println(s"${entry.getKey} = ${entry.getValue.unwrapped().toString}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may need it:

```
val sysProperties = System.getProperties
val allConfig = ConfigFactory.load("perks.conf")
val appConfig = allConfig.entrySet().filter { entry =>
  !sysProperties.containsKey(entry.getKey)
}
```

Comment: ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax("perks.conf") will fetch just the configs from the file and not add the System properties

Comment: You can use ConfigFactory.systemProperties().withFallback(yourConfig)