# Iterate over fields in typesafe config file

Tags: scala, typesafe

In my Scala application I have a configuration like this:

```
datasets {
    dataset1 = "path1"
    dataset2 = "path2"
    dataset3 = "path3"
}
```

Ho do I iterate over all the datasets to get a map [dataset, path]?

Comment: What is this? Scala code? If so, it looks strange and isn't useful without any definitions. If not, what are you asking? How to write a parser?

Comment: @dth It's a file for the typesafe config library. http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2014/02/leveraging-typesafes-config-library-across-environments/ gives a decent example of how to work with them. If no one's answered this later, I can probably write an answer, but I don't have time to play around with it right now (I only have a small amount of experience with this library)

Answer (score 4):

You can call `entrySet()` after getting config with `getConfig()`

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
val datasets = config.getConfig("datasets")
val configMap = datasets.entrySet().toList.map(
  entry => (entry.getKey, entry.getValue)
).toMap
```

You will end up with a `Map[String, ConfigValue]`.

Comment: A related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598856/iterate-over-fields-in-typesafe-config?rq=1) appears on the sidebar, you can look at the accepted answer, it has more description.

Comment: I get a Quoted ValueSet ,how to transform it to String -

Answer (score 0):

You can try my scala wrapper https://github.com/andr83/scalaconfig - it supports reading native scala types directly from config object:

```
val datasets = config.as[Map[String, String]]("datasets")
```